# value in form dependent on URL

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

schema.yml:

Shop:
  title:  { type: string(50) }
  number: { type: integer(2) }

i can set default value for number in ShopForm.class or method save. but how can i make it with address URL?

**http://www.myaddress.com/shop/new**

in **action.class.php (Shop.class.php)**

```
public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->form = new ShopForm();
  }
```

for example if i open address:

**http://www.myaddress.com/shop/new/number/2**

then automatically set number = 2 for this form.

thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can catch the parameter in the New Action doing this:

```
$this->number = $request->getParameter('number');
```

Doing that you can access to the `$number` variable in your template (where you build your form). Then in the form field where you specify the number value, just put something like this:

```
<input type="whatever" name="number" value="<?php echo $number?>">
```

hope this helped you! good luck